# How to remove glossiness applied to fondant?

Tags: fondant

I’ve applied a mixture of corn syrup/vodka to my fondant figurines to make them glossy. But they don’t look good. How can I remove the glossiness?

Comment: Welcome! Can you perhaps share a photo or two?

Comment: Fondant is glossy to begin with.

Comment: I have no idea it it would work if you applied a glaze, but for regular roller fondant on cakes, you can place something with texture on it and press it in to emboss it.  But you also need to do it before it’s hardened too much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.